# How to create a Drupal calendar with 2 digits (day date format) instead of 1?

Tags: 7, datetime

Does anybody have experience with adding a **0** before the numbers 1 to 9.
After this my calendar numbers should all have 2 digits: 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11...

I have added a new PHP date format ("d") and that should give 01 instead of 1 (according to the PHP manual).

But I don't know how to implement this in my calendar.

Answer (score 1):

At first you should add a date format on that page `admin/config/regional/date-time/formats/add`.

For example this format (`F d, Y`) gives you that result: **September 9, 2015**.

Then you can use it anywhere on your site.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I already did that, but 1 stays 1. I need 01. Any ideas?